# Want to create TextBox that can only accept value greater than previous entered

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I want to put validation on TextBox that it will only accept numeric or dateTime value greater than previous.
Please help me to do this.
Thanks,

Comment: Please show us [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a Class level variable of the Type you are checking, then when you validate correctly you set this to the current validated value it will prevent you from entering a lower value. Something like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int threshold = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out value))
        {
            if (value <= threshold)
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Value Must be Greater than " + threshold);
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.Clear();
                threshold = value;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Value Must be an integer");
        }

    }  
}
```